# How to calculate quantity where have the same skuid on mysql?

Tags: mysql, database

I have a query:

```
   select 
        -- a.id, a.`sales_order_no`, 
        a.`customer_id`, a.`fulfillment_date` ,b.`skuid`, b.`qty`
        from 
            `trx_sales_order` a,
            `trx_sales_order_detail` b
        where 
            a.`id` = b.`sales_order_id` and
            a.`customer_id` = 34 and a.`fulfillment_date` = '2019-10-18'
            order by b.`skuid`;
```

This is Result:

[image: Result of the Query]

I want to add up the quantity data from the same skuid. for example ,..
i have two records qty of skuid 10058, there are 1.00 and 2.00 = 3.00

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    -- a.id, a.`sales_order_no`, 
    a.`customer_id`, a.`fulfillment_date` ,b.`skuid`, SUM(b.`qty`)
    FROM 
        `trx_sales_order` a,
        `trx_sales_order_detail` b
    WHERE 
        a.`id` = b.`sales_order_id` AND
        a.`customer_id` = 34 AND a.`fulfillment_date` = '2019-10-18'
    GROUP BY a.`customer_id`, a.`fulfillment_date` ,b.`skuid`
        ORDER BY b.`skuid`;
```